# Assignability of two matching interfaces having different versions

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, interface

I have two Assemblies with the **same name** and the s**ame public key token**.
Both assemblies contain the **same interface** with the **same name** in the **same namespace**.

The only difference between the two assemblies is their version (1.0.0 vs 1.0.1).

But when calling

```
bool assignable1 = typeof(Interface1).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Interface2));
bool assignable2 = typeof(Interface2).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Interface1));
```

I get **FALSE** both times. Shouldn't those interfaces be assignable to each other?

Comment: Interface1 is defined in Assembly_1 and interface2 in Assembly_2?

Comment: Have you loaded both assemblies in your AppDomain? If yes, then you face a .Net Reflection bug, in short it looks like this: if you have some interface and load two libs with it into AppDomain, then .Net cannot resolve this interface, so casts like (IInterface)object won't work and, also, assignable won't work too. Check this out, hope i'm incorrect

Comment: How do you load both assemblies? Can you give some more context?

Comment: Yes, Interface 1 is from the first assembly, Interface 2 is from the second assembly. I load both of them using 'Assembly.LoadFrom(filname)' and 'assembly.GetType(name)'.

Comment: The questions remain: why should you expect to be able to load two different versions of the same assembly _and_ be able to assign types between the two? You're already loading the assemblies dynamically (obviously), so it's not like either type is compiled into the main program. In what situation would instances of these two different types even meet? The question taken literally ("shouldn't this work") is trivially answered as "no". But with more context, you might get an answer you and others could actually _use_.

Comment: There is an assembly containing an interface 'IExample'. This comes from vendor A. Then there's an assembly from vendor B, which contains an implementation of 'IExample'. Now vender A publishes a new version of his assembly but does not change 'IExample'. The customer now wants to be able to use the new assembly from vendor A, and the old assembly from vendor B by loading the old class into the new interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they shouldn't. Version matters, a lot. They are just two different classes in two different contexts.

I wonder even if your code actually works, since you can't load two assemblies with the same name in one `AppDomain`. It just takes the first one it loads.

I tried to reproduce your code using this:

```
Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFile(@"..\..\..\ClassLibrary2\bin\Debug\ClassLibrary2.dll");

//
// Last Interface1 loaded from referenced assembly
//
bool b = a.GetType("ClassLibrary1.Interface1").IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Interface1));
```

This will never ever work, unless `Interface1` is really an exact match (so version wise too). Even when you derive the interface it doesn't work as long as the version doesn't match. You should be able to workaround that using `assemblyBinding` though.

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="ClassLibrary1" publicKeyToken="12345" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.0.0.1" newVersion="1.0.0.1" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Then your `ClassLibrary2`, which implements an old version of `ClassLibrary1`'s interface should work.

Answer (score 2):

No, they shouldn't. They are different types, from different assemblies and modules.

Comment: What would I have to to do to make them the same type? It must be somehow possible to update my assembly to new versions without breaking compability to all applications using the assembly, right?

Comment: @Boris: Why are you doing this, what is your need, maybe there is a better solution?

Comment: I have two official Assemblies (v1.0.0 and v1.0.1) containing the same interface. My task is to provide an assembly implementing the interface from v1.0.1. But my class should also be able to be converted to the interface from v1.0.0, since both interfaces are the same.

Comment: @Ricardo is right. You can not assign `Interface1` to `Interface2` in C#, even if they are representing same set of methods with same signatures; and even if they were in the same assembly. Those are literally two different types. C# has not that kind of duck typing (yet).

Comment: @Boris: You can use composition, one class implement Interface(ver 1.0.0) and another one implements Interface(ver 1.0.1). Now a class instantiate this classes and switch between them.